# EXCEL VBA Run time error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I have a Macro in Xl with this code

```
Sub fileDelimiter(wb As Workbook)
    Const DELIMITER As String = "|"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myRecordSet As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim dataElementName As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If lastRow > 1 Then
        counter = 0
        'Debug.Print el_coll(Left(wb.Name, 5))
        dataElementName = el_coll(Left(wb.Name, 5))

        MyPath = "........\" & dataElementName & ".txt"
        
        If Dir(MyPath) = "" Then
            Set myRecordSet = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        ElseIf FileLen(MyPath) = 0 Then
            Set myRecordSet = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Else
            Set myRecordSet = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        End If

        nFileNum = FreeFile
        Open MyPath For Append As #nFileNum
        For Each myRecord In myRecordSet
            With myRecord
                For Each myField In Range(.Cells, _
                    Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                    sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
                Next myField
                Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
                sOut = Empty
            End With
        Next myRecord
        wb.Save
        Close #nFileNum
        wb.Close
    Else
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

I am so new on Excel VBA.it seems like I kept getting Run Time Error 5 running:

```
dataElementName = el_coll(Left(wb.Name, 5))
```

can you help me to find this issue?
Thank you

Comment: can you add the code for ```el_coll()```

Comment: I don't see the `wb` set in the code?

Comment: @Davesexcel It is passed as an argument into the sub.

Comment: Public el_coll As Collection is an array

Answer (score 0):

Is El_coll a UDF (User Defined function) in another module in your active workbook? if its not there you will get the error as the line cannot find the function to perform.

Comment: it is    Public el_coll As Collection

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit
Public el_coll As Collection

'The main subroutine to run to do everything
Sub run()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim dateRange As String
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim xFiles() As String
Dim extension As String
Dim vars As Variant

```
sheet_name = "Title Page"
extension = "xlsx"
Call init_data_el_coll
Call empty_txt_files(ActiveWorkbook.Path)
xFiles = ListAllFile(extension, ActiveWorkbook.Path)

dateRange = InputBox("Enter Data Date yyyy-mm: (Ex: 2014-02)")

If dateRange = "" Then
    Set el_coll = Nothing
    Call MsgBox("Cancelled operation", vbOKOnly, "Cancelled")
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each vars In xFiles
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(vars)
        Call delete_sheet(wb, sheet_name) 'Delete the sheet with the name
        wb.Save 'Save the changes
        Call text_manip(wb, dateRange)
    Next
    Set el_coll = Nothing
    Call MsgBox("Completed operation", vbOKOnly, "Completed")
End If
```

End Sub